# API laravel e angular

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel

Eu estou tentando fazer uma requisição usando angular conectando-se a REST API construído em laravel.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/rest/v1/entidades/licitacoes. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

Sei que a  API deve definir o cabeçalho, Contudo quando testo com o POSTMAN funciona normalmente. o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa configurar os cabeçalhos CORS para que a requisição partindo do browser funcione direitinho. Todos os browsers modernos fazem uma requisição conhecida como *preflight* antes da requisição ou postagem de dados propriamente dita, afim de conferir se é possível enviá-los.

Esse pacote Laravel ajuda a configurar o CORS na sua aplicação Laravel: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors